# How to show which users are running which processes and how much memory they take?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

everyone.

I am currently creating a little script in Bash.

I am trying to create a program that will show all running processes for every use and how much memory each process takes. I know I need to use the ps aux command.

Basically I want the output to look like this

```
USER     PROCESS    MEMORY
ROOT     Process1      10KB
         Process2     120KB
USER1    Process 1    50KB
         Process 4     1 KB
```

This is my code as of right now, I have no idea how to progress further

```
#!/bin/bash

runningUsers=$( ps aux | awk '{ print $1 }' | sed '1 d' | sort | uniq | perl -e 'for (<>) { chomp; $u = ( getpwnam($_) )[2]; print $_, "\n" if ( ( $u >= 1000 || $u == 0 ) && ( $_ =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ && $_ ne "nobody" ) ) }')
echo $runningUsers

users=($runningUsers)

echo "${users[0]}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pfoef, you're making it yourself really hard.
Why not stick with the basics, which already provide what you need.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
ps -eo user,pid,%mem,comm --sort=-%mem | awk '
BEGIN {
  printf "%-10s %-20s %-10s\n", "USER", "PROCESS", "MEMORY"
}
{
  printf "%-10s %-20s %-10s\n", $1, $4, sprintf("%.2f KB", $3*1024)
}'
```

the `printf %10` statements are for the width.

This script provides:

```
root@vm-local-1:~# ./test.sh
USER       PROCESS              MEMORY
USER       COMMAND              0.00 KB
root       unattended-upgr      512.00 KB
root       networkd-dispat      409.60 KB
root       multipathd           409.60 KB
root       systemd-journal      409.60 KB
systemd+   systemd-resolve      307.20 KB
```

Comment: Thank you it works, but I have a question, what if I wanted to make sums of the Memory for every user ? How could I make it ?